# Как поменять цвет текста на кнопках?

Tags: html, текст

Заранее говорю, что я в коде понимаю очень мало (практически ничего), поэтому не кидайте в меня пожалуйста помидоры.
Поставила подвал на сайт, просто сторонний код на другом сайте нашла. После вставки кода поменялся цвет на ссылках в меню и названиях товаров. Был черный, стал ярко синий.
[image: скринот сайта после вставки кода]
Вот код, который вставила:

```
HTML
```

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<!-- Footer -->
    <section id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center text-xs-center text-sm-left text-md-left">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <h5>Информация</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled quick-links">
            <li><a href="http://kiprus.ru/feedback"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Обратная связь</a></li>
            <li><a href="tel:8(969)400-46-90"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>+7(969)400-46-90</a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:info@kiprus.ru"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>info@kiprus.ru</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/blog"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Полезные статьи</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/o-kompanii"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>О компании</a></li>
                        
                        <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/dostavka"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Доставка</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/oplata"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Оплата</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <h5>Наша продукция</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled quick-links">
                        <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/avtomatika"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Автоматика</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/pribory-kontrolya"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Приборы контроля</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/pribory-dlya-tehnologicheskih-protsessov"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Приборы для технологических процессов</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/zapornaya-i-reguliruyuschaya-armatura"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Запорная и регулирующая арматура</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/kontrolno-izmeritelnye-pribory"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Контрольно-измерительные приборы</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/pribory-ucheta"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Приборы учета</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://kiprus.ru/soputstvuyuschie-tovary"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Сопутствующие товары</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <h5>Наш адрес</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled quick-links">
                        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A64c60aaf0a2ad265d0326abe3f4401c25673b2549427962ba2a7f47bcd2374e0&amp;width=320&amp;height=200&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
</ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-2 mt-sm-5">
                    
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-2 mt-sm-2 text-center text-white">
                    <a class="text-green ml-2" href="https://kiprus.ru/" target="_blank">© 2019-2022 Kiprus.ru Все права защищены </a></p>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- ./Footer -->
```

Заметила, что если убрать в начале HTML кода вот это

```
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

то ссылки становятся снова черными, но и подвал становится уродливым.

Нашла в интернете еще такой код:

```
    a:link {    /* unvisited link */    color: #384B7A;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {    /* visited link */    color: #384B7A;
      text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {    /* mouse over link */    color: #6FFF57;
      text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
a:active {    /* active link */    color: #000000;
      text-decoration: none;
}
```

Это помогло исправить цвет на ссылках, но при этом на всех градиентных кнопках текст тоже поменялся. Был белым, а теперь его практически не видно.
[image: скриншот сайта]

Как сделать так, чтобы текст на кнопках снова стал белый, а все остальное осталось темного цвета?
В тех поддержке платформы мне написали: Чтобы оставить подвал и вернуть стандартные стили вы можете добавить код сторонних стилей (из файла bootstrap.min.css) в файл user.css и убрать те, что перезаписывают стандартные. Это не гарантирует исправной работы системы.
В вашем случае перезаписываются стили ссылок (тег ).

Но мне ничего к сожалению не понятно, а больше они ничего не говорят. Может кто-то поможет мне... Буду очень благодарна. Сайт https://kiprus.ru/

Comment: Это вам на фриланс с такими задачами, скорее. Тут принято свои коды приносить и спрашивать, или хоть в чужом хорошо разбираться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш `файл user.css`:

```
.default-btn:link,
.default-btn:visited {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, это помогло, но я заметила, что у других кнопок на сайте "меню", "каталог" (в мобильной версии сайта видно) один class="c-button". Но у этих кнопок разный фон, одна серая, другая с темным градиентом. Как поменять цвет только на одной кнопке, чтобы другая не поменялась?

Comment: @СофияЧагина, можно ссылку, где это можно увидеть?

Comment: https://kiprus.ru/ Просто на главной через телефон если смотреть. https://pastenow.ru/dadbf48f6bd1f4956b71090fa7111eb2 - вот скриншот

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/58b191f6120d79183fb01f0da28310b0 - здесь скриншот с кодом, который относится к кнопке "каталог"

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/052df662afc7e2487ea25ed3ea9fdf77 - а это скрин с админ панели. Код отличается, в админке другое написано вместо класса

Comment: Ой, я нашла где эта информация находится, уже получилось поменять цвет. Извините, что потревожила вас

Answer (score 0):

Вместе с html кодом вы занесли файл со стилем, в котором наверное где-то прописаны ссылки синим цветом и все остальное. Либо удалите строчку, которую вы занесли. Либо если она нужна для подвала исправляйте повсюду вот такие истории как с кнопками. Совет если хотите что-то конкретное поменять, например  цвет шрифта в кнопках, кликните в хроме правой кнопкой -- вызовите функцию посмотреть код -- справа будут стили. Цвета вы точно определите. Далее обратите внимание на названия файлов и номера строк на которых должны быть изменения или скопируйте путь до файла. На своем сайте в менеджере файлов откройте тот или иной .css и поменяйте там цвет.